# How to check in file when file auto-uploaded to SharePoint Folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-rest-api

We have an automated job written in Python that uploads one file to a SharePoint location every day.  The problem is that this job leaves the uploaded file in a "Checked Out" status.  How can I ensure that the auto-uploaded document is Checked-In and available to end users?

I have discovered that if I disable the "Require Documents to be Checked Out before eding" option in the Library Settings, then the upload works as we need, but we need to leave this option turned on for future changes by other users.

Here is the current Python code that uploads the file:

```
  import requests
        from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
        session = requests.Session()
        session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth('DOMAIN\\username','password', session)

      my_headers = {
                    'accept' : 'application/vnd.ms-excel;odata=verbose',
                    'content-type' : 'application/vnd.ms-excel;odata=verbose',
                    'odata' : 'verbose',
                    'X-RequestForceAuthentication' : 'true',
                    'Connection': 'close'
                }


        put_url = 'https://site.com/test/2020%20Reports'
        with open('/home/user/template.xlsx','rb') as fin:
            myFile = requests.put('{}/template.xls'.format(put_url), 
                                  data=fin.read(), 
                                  auth=session.auth, 
                                  headers=my_headers)
```

How can I leave "require checkout" turned on, but still ensure that the uploaded file is checked in and available to contributors?

Comment: How is the file being uploaded? Is a user manually logging into SharePoint and uploading the file each day, or are you using an automated script or job?

Comment: We have some job which will upload the file to this folder automatically, but this is in checked out status. We want to automate this to check in automatically(only when the file is created).

Comment: What code/technology is the job using.  The same remote API's that are used to upload a file can be used to Check-in the file after upload is complete, but to give you an example, would need to know how this job is coded:  REST,CSOM,JSOM,PowerShell, etc.?  If you post the code snippet that is currently uploading the file, we can show you how to modify that code to finish checking in the file.

Comment: Thanks William. We are using python to upload the file. Tried different options, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using SharePoint's REST API to upload the file, so you would need to add a secondary call to the REST method that invokes a Check-In.  The documentation for the [File Check-in HTTP POST is here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-files-by-using-rest).  Luckily, it is one of the more simple calls to make, as it requires no body data. To Check in the file, you need to `POST` to `https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name/{file_name}')/CheckIn(comment='Comment',checkintype=0)`

You should be able to use the same session and headers you have already established for the file upload.  I am not a Python developer, but I think you need add the following to the end of your code:

```
checkin_url = "https://site.com/test/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/test/2020%20Reports/template.xls')/CheckIn(comment='Comment',checkintype=0)"
checkinResponse = requests.post(checkin_url, data='',auth=session.auth,headers=my_headers)
```

Comment: Thanks Willman. Do we need to use _api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl ? Can i use the final sharepoint url.

Comment: getting 404 error.

Comment: There should be some redundant overlap in your URLs.  The SiteUrl before the `/_api/web` is the full URL of the root of your site, but the Server-relative URL of your file still includes the folder portions of your path.  So, in the example in my posted answer, notice that it assumes you have a site named Test on the server `site.com`, but the file URL still has to start with `/test/`.

Comment: If you are allowed to post your actual URL, I can help troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks Willman.                                                                                                This url is almost similar to the below. "http://site.com/am/DIT/DDQ/Shared%20Documents/2018%20Docs%20Reports/Data%20Finds/Archive"

Comment: I have taken the complete url from browser and added the comment/check in section getting 200 response code but the file is not checked in. "http://site/am/DIT/DDQ/_layouts/xlviewer.aspx?id=/am/DIT/DDQ/Shared%20Documents/2018%20Docs%20Reports/Data%20Finds/Archive/file.xlsx/CheckIn(comment='Comment',checkintype=0)"

Comment: Based on those URLs, try setting your POST URL to this: `"http://site.com/am/DIT/DDQ/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/am/DIT/DDQ/Shared%20Documents/2018%20Docs%20Reports/Data%20Finds/Archive/file.xlsx')/CheckIn(comment='Comment',checkintype=0)"`

Comment: still getting the 404 error. When i try to add new file manually , the folder name it is showing /2018%20Docs%20Reports/Data%20Finds/Archive/ in sharepoint. Root Folder in the full url it is saying RootFolder=%2Fam%2FDIT%2DDQ%2FShared%20Documents%2F2018%20Docs%20Reports%2FData%20Finds%2FArchive...Looks like the doc library : http://site.com/am/DIT/DDQ/Shared%20Documents

Comment: The first folder i can see from http://site.com/am/DIT/DDQ/Shared%20Documents location. Getting 404 error when i use http://site.com/am. If i use http://site.com/am/DIT getting the heading page. If i use http://site.com/am/DIT/DDQ getting welcome to the sharepoint site. Please let me know if you can able to give some suggestions.

Comment: using put to place the file and post to check in the file

Comment: yes, `"http://site.com/am/DIT/DDQ"` is the url of your site, and `'/am/DIT/DDQ/Shared%20Documents/2018%20Docs%20Reports/Data%20Finds/Archive/file.xlsx'` is the **server-relative path** to your file, so you need to **POST** to `"http://site.com/am/DIT/DDQ/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/am/DIT/DDQ/Shared%20Documents/2018%20Docs%20Reports/Data%20Finds/Archive/file.xlsx')/CheckIn(comment='Comment',checkintype=0)"`

Comment: Thanks William. Was on vacation these days. I tried the same way. still getting 404 error. Am i missing anything . File showing as check out state. Is there anything missing in headers or sth , looks like not using 'X-RequestDigest' in the headers.Using the following headers -

Comment: using this header my_headers = {
            'accept' : 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'content-type' : 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'odata' : 'verbose',
            'X-RequestForceAuthentication' : 'true'
        }

Comment: Can you share your actual URL, something is apparently getting lost in translation from the fake site.com/am URL to your real one.

Comment: Looks like headers are not working fine . i use the title as well , but title is not placed when uploaded. Title is showing as blank. This is an excel file.

Comment: Shared%20Documents is the document library. http://xx-sharepoint.xxxxx.net/ib/DIT/DDQ/Shared%20Documents/2018%20Governance/Data%20Gaps/Analysis" is the exact url

Comment: Then your POST to `checkin_url = "http://xx-sharepoint.xxxxx.net/ib/DIT/DDQ/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/ib/DIT/DDQ/Shared%20Documents/2018%20Governance/Data%20Gaps/Analysis/template.xls')/CheckIn(comment='Comment',checkintype=0)"`.  Notice that there is a purposeful redudancy here, The url starts with the full path to the root of your SharePoint Site `http://xx-sharepoint.xxxxx.net/ib/DIT/DDQ`, and the Server-relative path to your file begins the the first part of the url after the domain (`.net`), `'/ib/DIT/DDQ/Shared%20Documents/2018%20Governance/Data%20Gaps/Analysis/template.xls'`

Comment: What about Header. Do you think that looks good. Am using content-type 'application/vnd.ms-excel or 'application/jason. File is uploaded if i use any of these.Am using data= '' and headers = my_headers which i used in put method

Comment: For the File.PUT, 'application/vnd.ms-excel' is correct,  For your Check-in, the content-type shouldn't matter because you are not including a `body` for this POST, but yes, generally for most API calls you want to set to 'application/json` (there is no 'a' in 'json'), or 'application/json;odata=verbose'.

Comment: Thanks.using data= '' Sorry. It's type mistake. Used only json. still am getting 404 error, not sure.Is there any settings we need to make sharepoint level

Comment: Is the check-in code being executed under the same user context as the user  account who uploaded the file?

Comment: Running in the same program and same user.using the same auth for both put and post. If i delete it is showing the original location as /ib/DIT/DDQ/Shared%20Documents/2018%20Governance/Data%20Gaps/Analysis in recycle bin

Comment: using %20 for the space. is that ok when we post

Comment: Yes, we generally encode spaces, and besides, if it didn't work then the file wouldn't have gotten successfully uploaded in the first place.

Comment: File is uploaded. I can able to see the file is sharepoint and even the file is not corrupted. file is in good shape. Modified by and checked out on my name

Comment: I remember without using post only file was uploaded when doing multiple trials.I thought it's working> i tried after after oneday and not checked in, not sure which options i used. After adding the headers.